# MariaDB - Get skewness & kurtosis for Descriptive Statistics

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to Get skewness & kurtosis by this SQL Query.

(For Descriptive Statistics)

Here is my Descriptive Statistics SQL Query.

(Please add more if I miss something in Descriptive statistics.)

```
SELECT 
  MainClass,
  COUNT(*) AS count_value,
  MIN(Amount) AS min_value,
  MAX(Amount) AS max_value,
  AVG(Amount) AS mean_value,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Amount) OVER () AS median_value,
  MAX(Amount) - MIN(Amount) AS range_value,
  STDDEV_POP(Amount) AS standard_deviation,
  VAR_POP(Amount) AS variance,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Amount) OVER () AS percentile_25,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Amount) OVER () AS percentile_50,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Amount) OVER () AS percentile_75,
  (SUM(POWER(Amount - AVG(Amount), 3)) / (COUNT(*) * POWER(STDDEV_POP(Amount), 3))) AS skewness,
  (SUM(POWER(Amount - AVG(Amount), 4)) / (COUNT(*) * POWER(STDDEV_POP(Amount), 4))) AS kurtosis
FROM 
  (SELECT *
   FROM Expenditure
   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Created, INTERVAL 9 HOUR), '%Y-%m') = '2023-03'
     AND AccountEmail = 'example@meow.com') AS CurrentMonthExpenditure
GROUP BY 
  MainClass;
```

This part does not work.

```
  (SUM(POWER(Amount - AVG(Amount), 3)) / (COUNT(*) * POWER(STDDEV_POP(Amount), 3))) AS skewness,
  (SUM(POWER(Amount - AVG(Amount), 4)) / (COUNT(*) * POWER(STDDEV_POP(Amount), 4))) AS kurtosis
```

error message is "SQL Error [1111] [HY000]: (conn=27) Invalid use of group function
(conn=27) Invalid use of group function
(conn=27) Invalid use of group function"

How can I fix this?

My MariaDB Version is 10.11.2-MariaDB

Comment: Do the aggregation on two steps. Use a derived table (FROM clause subquery) for the first step.